# Fire event based on object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like

```
let obj = { 
        1: true, 
        2:false,
        3:true
}
```

How can i return the object key wherever the object value is false, for example, in the case above, only `2` should be returned

I tried `Object.values(obj).filter(value => !value)` but it only returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `filter()` on `Object.values()` this way you will not have any way to access the corresponding key

You can use `filter()` on `Object.keys()` and check if value at that key is truthy.

```js
let obj = { 
        1: true, 
        2:false,
        3:true
}
const res = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => !obj[k]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, came up with

`Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => !value).map(([key, value]) => key);`

which returns what I need.

Comment: This is complex way to that. See my answer

Comment: You should use Object.keys() instead, to simplify this - see @MaheerAli's answer